# mysql_fetch_array only show one row

Tags: html, sql

I had some issue on display my data from database after updating my database. Here is the code I am using, is there any error or reason why it only returned one row?

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM report";        
    $myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
        $data[] = array(
        $id = $row['id'],
        $case_number = $row['case_number'],
        $contents = $row['contents'],
            );

    }

    ?>
    <section>
    <form action="sqlstatement.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="case_number" value=" <?php echo $case_number; ?>" />
        <input type="text" name="contents" value=" <?php echo $contents; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value=" <?php echo $id; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" name="edit" value="edit"/>
        <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete"/>

        <?php echo $case_number; ?>
    </form>
```

Thank you.

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: Yes, you're only outputting one row. How do you expect this to output several rows if you're only outputting a single `<form>`?

Comment: isnt `$data[] = array(` should be `$data[counter] = array(` where counter is the counter that will be incrementing in while loop

Answer (score 1):

You fetch all rows in a `while loop`, but you don't use any of that data. You just overwrite the same variables over and over again.

Only when the loop is finished, a form is outputted once, with the current values of those variables. 
The result is that you see only the last row of the query results.

Comment: Hello GolezTrol, Is there any way of displaying all result using form?

Comment: @Crescent : after giving hint, can't you try and tell us with the problem you are facing? atleast try man...

Comment: Hello Fahim, after getting the hint, I do know why to change? Therefore, I asked again.:( And then if i placed my form in php echo, I only can edit one word instead a sentence.

Comment: @Crescent There are a plenty of ways, although editing multiple records at once isn't very easy, and I'm starting to think you are lacking a lot of knowledge in this area. StackOverflow isn't suitable for complete tutorials, so I think you'd better start simple, trying a lot by yourself and asking specific questions as you go.

Answer (score 0):

The variable $case_number is not an array. Change the variable to array then it accepts multiple values.

your current code shows only the last value from the while loop.

Comment: Vinoth, do you mind to show me an example? Thank you